# How do I unmount my react app before it's removed from the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a modal that opens and my react app is dropped into it. The jQuery modal plugin comes with the ability to close the modal via the escape key, clicking on the close x, or on the modal mask. When the modal closes it removes the react app via jquery remove(). This is a problem because it can possibly cause memory leaks without clearing settimeouts and setintervals or removing listeners if the app is not properly unmounted.

The React app inside the modal has a cancel button that also closes the modal. I have a function where I unmount the app via React.unmountComponentAtNode() when the cancel button is clicked, before I call the jquery modal plugin to close the modal, and it works great!

I'm wondering if there is a way to intercept the call that closes the modal from the plugin and run the unmounting function first, or some clever trickery to make sure the component is umounted before it's removed from the dom by the plugin. (I don't have access to make changes to the plugin or make the modal container and mask part of the react app just yet.)

Comment: Doesn't the plugin have a `onCloseModal` callback or something similar?

Comment: I eneded up goint with this: https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f. Also adding touchstart and pointerdown, as these events will fire before the click events do.